# Image Manipulation using Average Kernel

Tags: c#, image, vision

Ive been working on a code that takes an image, turns it into grayscale, and then does image manipulation depending on which button is pressed. When a button is pressed (ex. Average 3x3, Prewitt 5x5), it calls a 2D Multiplication function, which loops over the grayscale image, while looping over the kernel, adding all the values in the matrix. If any value is over 255, it sets it to 255. Then using the SetPixel on a temporary bitmap variable, which is finally put into the picturebox. When i run the program, I select an image and it shows it (as grayscale), but after choosing one of the filters, the program freezes for around 30 seconds, and then nothing changes, no filter is applied. Ive tried debugging and i cant seem to locate what the problem is!

EDIT: The initial question has been solved( I had to refresh the picturebox for the new image to show properly.
But i am facing another problem here with regards to the prewitt kernel.

i get this error 
"Additional information: Value of '-6' is not valid for 'red'. 'red' should be greater than or equal to 0 and less than or equal to 255."

And i am not sure what to change in my code to fix this.

Initializing:

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    private Image img;
    Bitmap grayscaleimage;
    double[][] AVGKernel = new double[11][];
    double[][] PrewittKernel = new double[11][];
    int[] AVGKernal1DH = new int[11];
    int[] AVGKernal1DV = new int[11];

    Bitmap tempBitmap;

    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        for (int i = 0; i < 11; i++)
        {
            AVGKernel[i] = new double[11];
            PrewittKernel[i] = new double[11];
            for (int j = 0; j < 11; j++)
            {
                AVGKernel[i][j] = 0;
                PrewittKernel[i][j] = 0;
                AVGKernal1DH[j] = 0;
                AVGKernal1DV[j] = 0;
            }
        }
}
```

The open button and turning the picture into grayscale:

```
private void OpenImageButton(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        OpenFileDialog openFileDialog = new OpenFileDialog();
        if (openFileDialog.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
        {
            this.img = Image.FromFile(openFileDialog.FileName);

            grayscaleimage = new Bitmap(img);
            int rgb;
            Color c;

            for (int y = 0; y < grayscaleimage.Height; y++)
                for (int x = 0; x < grayscaleimage.Width; x++)
                {
                    c = grayscaleimage.GetPixel(x, y);
                    rgb = (int)((c.R + c.G + c.B) / 3);
                    grayscaleimage.SetPixel(x, y, Color.FromArgb(rgb, rgb, rgb));
                }
            this.pictureBox1.BackgroundImage = grayscaleimage;
            pictureBox1.BackgroundImageLayout = ImageLayout.Zoom;
        }
    }
```

an example of the many buttons available:

```
private void button5_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        AVGKernel[0][0] = 1; AVGKernel[0][1] = 1; AVGKernel[0][2] = 1; AVGKernel[0][3] = 1; AVGKernel[0][4] = 1;
        AVGKernel[1][0] = 1; AVGKernel[1][1] = 1; AVGKernel[1][2] = 1; AVGKernel[1][3] = 1; AVGKernel[1][4] = 1;
        AVGKernel[2][0] = 1; AVGKernel[2][1] = 1; AVGKernel[2][2] = 1; AVGKernel[2][3] = 1; AVGKernel[2][4] = 1;
        AVGKernel[3][0] = 1; AVGKernel[3][1] = 1; AVGKernel[3][2] = 1; AVGKernel[3][3] = 1; AVGKernel[3][4] = 1;
        AVGKernel[4][0] = 1; AVGKernel[4][1] = 1; AVGKernel[4][2] = 1; AVGKernel[4][3] = 1; AVGKernel[4][4] = 1;

        kernal2DMultiplication(AVGKernel, 5);
        this.pictureBox1.BackgroundImage = tempBitmap;

    }
```

Prewitt 5x5 kernel

```
 private void button13_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        PrewittKernel[0][0] = 2; PrewittKernel[0][1] = 1; PrewittKernel[0][2] = 0; PrewittKernel[0][3] = -1; PrewittKernel[0][4] = -2;
        PrewittKernel[1][0] = 2; PrewittKernel[1][1] = 1; PrewittKernel[1][2] = 0; PrewittKernel[1][3] = -1; PrewittKernel[1][4] = -2;
        PrewittKernel[2][0] = 2; PrewittKernel[2][1] = 1; PrewittKernel[2][2] = 0; PrewittKernel[2][3] = -1; PrewittKernel[2][4] = -2;
        PrewittKernel[3][0] = 2; PrewittKernel[3][1] = 1; PrewittKernel[3][2] = 0; PrewittKernel[3][3] = -1; PrewittKernel[3][4] = -2;
        PrewittKernel[4][0] = 2; PrewittKernel[4][1] = 1; PrewittKernel[4][2] = 0; PrewittKernel[4][3] = -1; PrewittKernel[4][4] = -2;

        kernal2DMultiplication(PrewittKernel, 5);
        this.pictureBox1.BackgroundImage = tempBitmap;
        this.pictureBox1.Refresh();
    }
```

and finally, the function being called:

```
private void kernal2DMultiplication(double[][] kernel, int size)
    {
        tempBitmap = grayscaleimage;
        double nrgb = 0;

        for (int i = 0; i < grayscaleimage.Width - size / 2; i++)
        {
            for (int j = 0; j < grayscaleimage.Height - size / 2; j++)
            {
                if (i >= size / 2 && j >= size / 2)
                {
                    for (int k = 0; k < size; k++)
                        for (int l = 0; l < size; l++)

                            nrgb += grayscaleimage.GetPixel(i + k - (size / 2), j + l - (size / 2)).R * kernel[k][l];
                            nrgb = nrgb / (size * size);

                    if (nrgb > 255)
                        nrgb = 255;

                    tempBitmap.SetPixel(i, j, Color.FromArgb((int)nrgb, (int)nrgb, (int)nrgb));

                }

            }

        }
    }
```

Comment: If you save the grey scale image, `grayscaleimage`, to a file and open it in, say, Paint (or similar) are you seeing the grey image or is it black?

Comment: Hmmm, GetPixel / SetPixel are relatively slow operations. Maybe by adding `Debug.WriteLine` statements you can see what code is executing and where you are ending up in an endless loop (if this happens).

Comment: The 30 second freeze may be caused by the fact that `SetPixel` is very, very slow.  As for the failure to update the screen, perhaps you're not forcing a repaint?

Comment: @Sjips i did debugg, it doesnt go into an infinite loop, the values actually do update!

Comment: @dbc i dont have a problem with the waiting, i just want it to eventually give me the expected output. i would have guessed that this.pictureBox1.BackgroundImage = tempBitmap; would normally be enough to repaint the background with the new bitmap?

Comment: @Omar Younis - but it's still the same bitmap pointer, right?  You're changing its RGB data, but `tempBitmap = grayscaleimage` so you're actually changing the pre-existing background image in-place, right?

Comment: If, during the freeze, you click the 'Break all' button (the pause button) in Visual Studio, where does it break?

Comment: Try doing [`this.pictureBox1.Refresh()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.refresh.aspx) after setting the bitmap, since it seems you're changing the bitmap in-place rather than copying, modifying, then setting the copy.

Comment: @Sjips just tried, nrgb += grayscaleimage.GetPixel(i + k - (size / 2), j + l - (size / 2)).R * kernel[k][l];

Comment: @Sjips yeah they are, its working now, i just needed to refresh the picturebox, thank you for your help!

Comment: Congratulations! I removed my last comment because it appeared that a solution is available.

Comment: @dbc i edited the original post and added an extra question I am facing instead of having to re-write most of this post again, can you please check it out too?

Comment: @Omar Younis - sounds like you have another exception.  What you should do is [make visual studio break when the exception is thrown](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/d14azbfh.aspx), find out exactly where it happens, then if you can't solve the problem, ask another question.  The preferred format for stackoverflow is [one question per question](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/39223/one-post-with-multiple-questions-or-multiple-posts).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that you are modifying the `BackgroundImage` bitmap in-place rather than copying, modifying the copy, and then setting the copy to be the `BackgroundImage`:

```
    this.pictureBox1.BackgroundImage = grayscaleimage; // initially

    tempBitmap = grayscaleimage; 

    // Make changes to tempBitmap

    this.pictureBox1.BackgroundImage = tempBitmap; // actually still the same pointer
```

The `BackgroundImage` setter is not forcing a redraw of the control in this case.  To force this yourself, call [`Refresh()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.refresh.aspx):

```
    this.pictureBox1.Refresh();
```

To improver performance, look into replacing multiple calls to [`SetPixel`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.drawing.bitmap.setpixel%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) with a single call to [`LockBits`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.drawing.bitmap.lockbits%28v=vs.110%29.aspx).  See e.g. [here](http://tech.pro/tutorial/660/csharp-tutorial-convert-a-color-image-to-grayscale).